# Is the MySQL Entity Framework Connector Incompatible with OrderBy()?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

I'm using the MySQL Entity Framework Connector to connect to my MySQL Database.

Is it compatible with any order by functionality?  Whenever I remove `.OrderBy()` from the code below, it works fine, but with it I get an error.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using uQuiz.Domain;
using uQuiz.Domain.Abstract;

namespace uQuiz.WebUI.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class DashboardController : Controller
    {
        private QuizEntities Context;

        public DashboardController(QuizEntities context)
        {
            this.Context = context;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The quiz dashboard
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            // Get the logged in user ID
            int userId = Convert.ToInt32(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            IEnumerable<Quiz> usersQuizzes = this.Context.Quizzes.Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.Deleted == false).OrderBy(d => d.CreatedTime).ToList();

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

> An exception of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command
>   definition. See the inner exception for details.
>
> Inner Exception Message: Unknown column 'Project1.C1' in 'field list'

**This works**

```
IEnumerable<Quiz> usersQuizzes = this.Context.Quizzes.Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.Deleted == false).ToList();
```

**This Doesn't**

```
IEnumerable<Quiz> usersQuizzes = this.Context.Quizzes.Where(x => x.UserId == userId && x.Deleted == false).OrderBy(d => d.CreatedTime).ToList();
```

Here is the `Quiz` class that relates to `Quizzes` auto generated from my EDMX:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace uQuiz.Domain
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Quiz
    {
        public Quiz()
        {
            this.Answers = new HashSet<Answer>();
            this.FeaturedQuizzes = new HashSet<FeaturedQuiz>();
            this.PersonalityOutcomes = new HashSet<PersonalityOutcome>();
            this.PossibleAnswers = new HashSet<PossibleAnswer>();
            this.Questions = new HashSet<Question>();
            this.QuizLinks = new HashSet<QuizLink>();
            this.QuizPasswords = new HashSet<QuizPassword>();
            this.QuizSubmissons = new HashSet<QuizSubmission>();
            this.QuizVersions = new HashSet<QuizVersion>();
            this.ResultDescriptions = new HashSet<ResultDescriptions>();
            this.Takers = new HashSet<Taker>();
        }

        public long Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public long QuizVersionId { get; set; }
        public string IPAddress { get; set; }
        public int IsPublic { get; set; }
        public string QuizType { get; set; }
        public long CreatedTime { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> BackgroundId { get; set; }
        public string UrlId { get; set; }
        public long PasswordsDisabled { get; set; }
        public long SharedFacebook { get; set; }
        public long SharedTwitter { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Deleted { get; set; }
        public long ShowCorrections { get; set; }
        public long ShowBreakdown { get; set; }
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string ShareImage { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> LinkId { get; set; }
        public long ForceShareImage { get; set; }
        public long ShareCount { get; set; }
        public string BackgroundAlign { get; set; }
        public string BackgroundColour { get; set; }
        public string TextColour { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<FeaturedQuiz> FeaturedQuizzes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PersonalityOutcome> PersonalityOutcomes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PossibleAnswer> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
        public virtual QuizBackground QuizBackgrounds { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuizLink> QuizLinks { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuizPassword> QuizPasswords { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuizSubmission> QuizSubmissons { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<QuizVersion> QuizVersions { get; set; }
        public virtual User Users { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ResultDescriptions> ResultDescriptions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Taker> Takers { get; set; }
        public virtual QuizVersion QuizVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Update 1

I have generated a new EDMX from the same database within the same project called `QuizEntities2` and this works fine, the only difference being that I haven't been through and changed the names for the mappings... here's the code I have within my controller.  One works and the other doesn't it comes up with the error.

```
using (QuizEntities context1 = new QuizEntities())
{
    // ERROR: Unknown column 'Project1.C1' in 'field list'
    var quizzes1 = context1.Quizzes.Where(x => x.UserId == 1 && x.Deleted == false).OrderByDescending(x => x.CreatedTime).Skip(5).Take(5).ToList();
}

using (QuizEntities2 context2 = new QuizEntities2())
{
    // Works completely fine
    var quizzes = context2.quizzes.Where(x => x.user_id == 1 && x.deleted == false).OrderByDescending(x => x.created_time).Skip(5).Take(5).ToList();
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="QuizEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/QuizModel.csdl|res://*/QuizModel.ssdl|res://*/QuizModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;database=uquiznew&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    <add name="QuizEntities2" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelModel.Model1.csdl|res://*/ModelModel.Model1.ssdl|res://*/ModelModel.Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;database=uquiznew2&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="uQuiz.OwinStart" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.0.0" newVersion="5.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Equivalent Quiz Class for Working DbContext**

The auto pluralizer has mucked up the name and called it `Quizze` and I haven't changed it because I have just been testing a new EDMX...

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace uQuiz.Domain.ModelModel
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class quizze
    {
        public quizze()
        {
            this.answers = new HashSet<answer>();
            this.featured_quizzes = new HashSet<featured_quizzes>();
            this.personality_outcomes = new HashSet<personality_outcomes>();
            this.possible_answers = new HashSet<possible_answers>();
            this.questions = new HashSet<question>();
            this.quiz_links = new HashSet<quiz_links>();
            this.quiz_passwords = new HashSet<quiz_passwords>();
            this.quiz_submissions = new HashSet<quiz_submissions>();
            this.quiz_versions = new HashSet<quiz_versions>();
            this.result_descriptions = new HashSet<result_descriptions>();
            this.takers = new HashSet<taker>();
        }

        public long quiz_ID { get; set; }
        public long user_id { get; set; }
        public long quiz_version_id { get; set; }
        public string ip_address { get; set; }
        public int @public { get; set; }
        public string quiz_type { get; set; }
        public long created_time { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> background_id { get; set; }
        public string url_id { get; set; }
        public long passwords_disabled { get; set; }
        public long shared_facebook { get; set; }
        public long shared_twitter { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> deleted { get; set; }
        public long show_corrections { get; set; }
        public long show_breakdown { get; set; }
        public string thumbnail { get; set; }
        public string share_image { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> link_id { get; set; }
        public long force_share_image { get; set; }
        public long share_count { get; set; }
        public string background_align { get; set; }
        public string background_colour { get; set; }
        public string text_colour { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<answer> answers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<featured_quizzes> featured_quizzes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<personality_outcomes> personality_outcomes { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<possible_answers> possible_answers { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<question> questions { get; set; }
        public virtual quiz_backgrounds quiz_backgrounds { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<quiz_links> quiz_links { get; set; }
        public virtual quiz_links quiz_links1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<quiz_passwords> quiz_passwords { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<quiz_submissions> quiz_submissions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<quiz_versions> quiz_versions { get; set; }
        public virtual quiz_versions quiz_versions1 { get; set; }
        public virtual user user { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<result_descriptions> result_descriptions { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<taker> takers { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the double . in d..CreatedTime intentional and correct?

Comment: Sorry, that was untentional.  I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the . appearing twice in d..CreatedTime, (but that probably didn't fix it)
CreatedTime must also be a field property and not a method. (I suspect it can be a method). Linq tries to convert your command to SQL, and SQL knows fields, but not your C# methods.

Also, ordering by a timestamp is suspicious, since values will all likely be unique, and it won't add ordering.

Otherwise, we'd have to inspect your class definition and compare it to the sql table definition.

Comment: Thanks.  My models are database first so all the classes are auto generated from the database.  CreatedTime is a Unix time stamp so it will order them in the order that the user created them.  I guess if it wasnt a field then it wouldn't compile?

Comment: If it is a method, it compiles, but it wouldn't map to SQL. So you have to show the Quiz class definition, especially the CreatedTime part.

Comment: I've just set up a new project with the same libraries, but I've reverse engineered code first rather than database first/EDMX and the query works completely fine.  I wonder what difference that makes?  The definition of CreatedTime is is the same `public long CreatedTime { get; set; }`

Comment: I just decided to reverse engineer my database for code first within my existing project and the same query works fine... what is the difference between edmx and code first when it comes to linq queries?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is that I am using the same Database Context for my ASP.NET Identity.  I've posted the Quiz class now ^^

Comment: I've just tried to query another one of my databases using that context, a different unrelated table and it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out what the issue was.  I had changed the type of the primary key `Id` on my Users table to `Int32` so that I could use it with Identity Framework.

When I first generate my EDMX file, it generated it as `Int64`.

I changed the data type back to `Int64` as it was originally generated and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this error, updating the entity model from database solved the issue.

Comment: I think this may also be related to failing to add the attribute to the DbContext that is described on the Entity Framework 6 MySql 'Get Started' page.